# Making a combination of 2 bubbles in CSS

Tags: css

I am struggling with designing this element in CSS
http://www.oinobareion.at/files/css_bubble.png

It is no problem to make one bubble:

```
.bubble_yellow {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #facf35;
    border: solid 16px #fff0cf;
}
```

But how can I somehow "include" the smaller bubble into the shape of the other one? Is it even possible with CSS?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/epujab/1/ (only chrome tested) ;)

Comment: wow! can you explain the code in one or two sentences?

Comment: It actually is just a set of layers positioned on-top of each other. The problem to solve is: 1) keep the shadows in the background, 2: don't let the border "cut" into the inner shapes, 3) visually merge the inner shapes. To achieve that, the shadows are in the background, then the borders and on top the inner shapes.

Answer (score 4):

This is reasonably easy to achieve with the CSS pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`. Using these, your markup stays clean.

[image: Example]

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Chg/)

Here, I'm layering the elements with `:after` at the lowest layer. This is the layer with `box-shadow` on it. Having this right at the bottom means there's no overlap of shadow between adjacent elements. It's absolutely positioned to align with the element itself.

Next is the `:before` pseudo element. This is also absolutely positioned, and has a yellow background to give the yellow border effect.

Lastly is the element itself, which is orange in the demo.

All layers have `border-radius: 100%` to make them round whatever size the element may be.

#### Layer breakdown:

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div id="blubbles">
    <div class="bubble" id="small"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="large"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#blubbles {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f60;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

/* Yellow border */
.bubble:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    content: "";
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Box shadow */
.bubble:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    content: "";
    z-index: -2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#small {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
#large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Great solution - inspired me to update my answer to make it work with just one HTML element!

Comment: @Marco I liked your answer as it was - it gave users a choice between more CSS or (a little) more HTML, although I'm glad I can be an inpsiration

Comment: This is a great answer! And really nice illustrations :-)

Comment: Thanks very much. To me, descriptions and explanations make an answer, not just "do it like this" `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works. It combines the use of `filter: drop-shadow` to create the shadow around the shapes, and some absolute positioning to hide the borders.

**HTML**

```
<div class="orbs">
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.orbs
{
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px black);
}

.orbs div
{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    border:5px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
}

.big
{
    z-index:1;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.small
{
    z-index:2;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}

.big-overlay
{
    z-index:3;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    background-color:red !important;
    border:0 !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mBbVg/).

Take note the `filter:` CSS property isn't supported in every browser (yet) ([reference](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)), and the demo only works in `-webkit-` enabled browsers.

**== UPDATE ==**

When looking at the great answer from [Bojangles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383609/bojangles), and combining it with mine, you could create this shape using just one single HTML element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.shape
{
    margin:50px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:1;

    background-color:red;
    border:5px solid orange;
    position:absolute;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px black);
}

.shape:before
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;

    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    border:5px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
}

.shape:after
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    z-index:3;

    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red !important;
    border:0 !important;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wfCpH/).

Comment: I finally followed your description and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hum, the only thing I can think off is to use z-index to put the smaller bubble in front off the first one,but it will have it's whole border, not as in the exemple
as boz said, I don't think it's possible otherwise

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing. Thanks for the help!